# Python - Function Name Importation

Tags: python

I'm importing a package for a game with functions such as moveUp(), moveDown(), moveLeft() and moveRight(). I am trying to create a function that will loop any of these commands for a designated number.

I am currently using the following code:

```
def moveUpLoop(loopNo):
    for i in range(0, loopNo):
        world.moveUp()

def moveDownLoop(loopNo):
    for i in range(0, loopNo):
        world.moveDown()

def moveLeftLoop(loopNo):
    for i in range(0, loopNo):
        world.moveLeft()

def moveRightLoop(loopNo):
    for i in range(0, loopNo):
        world.moveRight()
```

However I would like to use something like the following:

```
def functionLoop(funcName, loopNo):
    for i in range(0, loopNo):
        world.funcName()

functionLoop(moveRight, 5)
```

When I try to do this, I get this error:

NameError: global name 'moveRight' is not defined

Is there anyway around this? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

```
def functionLoop(funcName, loopNo):
    for i in range(loopNo):
        getattr(world, funcName)()

functionLoop('moveRight')
```

or

```
def functionLoop(func, loopNo):
    for i in range(loopNo):
        func()

functionLoop(world.moveRight)
```

Answer (score 0):

`getattr` is the function you're looking for. However, that sort of pattern seems more suited to a dictionary:

```
direction_mapping = {
    "up": world.moveUp,
    "down": world.moveDown,
    "left": world.moveLeft,
    "right": world.moveRight
}

def move_loop(direction, loopno):
    direction_func = direction_mapping[direction]
    for i in range(loopno):
        direction_func()

move_loop("right", 5)
```

Of course, at that point I'd probably even change the whole design so that `world` has a `move` method that takes a `direction` argument.